# Time Machine cannot connect to Synology NAS via Wi-Fi. Everything goes well via ethernet cable

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, nas

NAS: synology DS414 (with updated firmware); OS: osx 10.9 (maverick)

USE CASE OF THE PROBLEM

1. I arrive at home, my NAS is correctly connected to my wi-fi router.
2. I start my macbook pro which automatically connects to my LAN via Wi-Fi.
3. Time Machine attempts to backup.
4. Time Machine remains some minutes in "Looking for backup disk..." status.
5. Time Machine goes in time out and reports "Backup delayed"

NOTES

1. During the use case above, Finder doesn't show the DiskStation icon in the "SHARED" list (located at the bottom of the sidebar of any finder window, screenshot: http://o7.no/1pP95KY).
2. Once I connect my mac to LAN vi Ethernet, Finder immediately mounts DiskStation server and shows DiskStation icon in "SHARED" list. If I click the DiskStation icon, finder connects to DiskStation as "admin".
3. If I perform the point 2 above, then Time Machine is able to find the backup disk and complete the backup.
4. If I disconnect the Ethernet cable, DiskStation immediately disappears from the "SHARED" list. If I disconnect the Ethernet cable during Time Machine backup, the Time Machine backup is NOT interrupted and it is completed with success.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kurt I had a similar problem with Time Machine and Lion (10.75), but mine was over Ethernet (DS212J). Something is definitely flaky with the networking software here. For days backups would be delayed or the device couldn't be found. I eventually found a post that said avoid long reaches of Ethernet so I bought myself a smart switch (GS108T) for my desk, moved my DS there and connected everything with 3' Ethernet cables - now everything works great, downside now is that my wife's Mac will suffer the same problems as above. I'm hoping a future firmware upgrade will fix this. It was a really frustrating time and I'm still not satisfied with the solution. Good luck.